# Load URL within JSON in UIWebView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, url, uiwebview

My JSON reads like this:

```
{
  "sites": [
    {
      "name": "lovely.com",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.trial.com\/lovely\/",
      "price": "1795",
    },
    {
      "name": "great.com",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.trial.com\/great\/",
      "price": "1730",
    },

    {
      "name": "food.com",
      "url": "http:\/\/www.trial.com\/food\/",

      "price": "1195",
    },
```

I need the url of the specified site to open in a separate UIWebView when the user clicks on the "buy" button. Here is a snippet of my current code:

**ViewController.m**

```
-(void)buyBttnPressed:(id)sender{

    UIWebView *buyView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,132,280,368)];
    buyView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    buyView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
    buyView.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:buyView];

   // [buyView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:_url]]];


}
```

I have already parsed the JSON file. I'm just trying to figure out how to open the url(s) in the WebView using the url object key . . .

Comment: So whats happening when you call loadRequest ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385210/how-to-open-url-from-string-in-webview-for-iphone

Comment: NSString *webUrl=[[arrParsedData valueForKey:@"sites"]valueForKey:@"url"];  ,using this u can get url form json data. @iosLove14

Comment: Do you know how to open the URL http:/ /www.trial.com/food/ ? If yes, the URL is just an NSString in your JSON data. If not, this has nothing to do with JSON.

Comment: Have you considered looking at the documentation for UIWebView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify code as below

```
NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",url];

[buyView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]]];

////(OR) If are using NSObject say Location to store the details you can refer below code

UIButton *btn=(UIButton *)sender;

Location *locObj=[self.dataArray objectAtIndex:btn.tag];

NSString *urlString=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",locObj.url];

[buyView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstring]]];

int i=-1;

for(NSDictionary *dict in dataarray)
{
   i++;
   btn.tag=i;
}
```

Hope it helps you...!

Comment: Thanks @Vidhyanand900! This helped me out a lot! The only problem is that when I open the webview, it opens the same url every time. As I review the console, I see that the url that it keeps opening is at index 0, which must mean that tag (in btw.tag) is 0. How do I fix this?..

Comment: Instead of btn.tag..You need to pass the index of array like 0 or 1 or 2. As per your requirement..Where you are displaying the parsed content in tableview or any other object...?

Comment: The parsed content is being displayed on a separate UIView like a card. There are a total of 75 cards loaded/being parsed in an array at once.

Comment: You are displaying all the parsed data or only the selected one parse data(Single record)?

Comment: 75 cards are loaded/being parsed in an array at once.

Comment: If you are loading card data using for loop like for(int i=0,i<array.count;i++) then set btn.tag=i;. You need to set tag to button while displaying card content in seperate view...

Comment: My for loop looks like this: for (NSDictionary *dict1 in dataArray)

Comment: Then I initialize my custom object: MyObject *customObj = [[MyObject alloc]init];   customObject.name = [customObj valueForKey @"name"];   ... and so on. Then I add the objects to a mutable array.

Comment: Check my updated answer..You need to do as above..Then it will update and my code will work..

Comment: I played around with the integer and I saw the correlation between the int (i) and the tag index. For some reason, the tag and the selected index are not matching as they should..

Answer (score 0):

Use the Json element where you saved all the links,let's say that your JsonElement is called

> Location

the code should be something like this:

```
NSURL *nsurl=[NSURL URLWithString:Location.url];
NSURLRequest *nsrequest=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:nsurl];
[webview loadRequest:nsrequest];
```

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
    NSError *error;
    NSJSONSerialization *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:parseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
    NSString *strURL = [[[jsonData valueForKey:@"sites"]objectAtIndex:selectedIndex]valueForKey:@"url"];
    [buyView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]]];
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try this

create a custom method to get json data as an array..

```
-(NSArray *)getDataDictionaryFromJsonFile:(NSString *)jsonFileName
{
    NSData *fileContents = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jsonFileName ofType:@"json"]];
    NSError *error;
    NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:fileContents options:kNilOptions error:&error];
    NSArray * array = [dict objectForKey:@"sites"];
    return array;
}
```

now call this method where ever you want,
like

```
 NSArray *  sitesArray = [self getDataDictionaryFromJsonFile:@"Sites"];
 NSURL * url = [NSURL urlFromString:[[sitesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"url"]];
 NSLog(@"lovely URL:%@",[[sitesArray objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"url"]);
```

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way to do that is by using AFNetworking library [here](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
Add AFNetworking to your project and import AFNetworking.h and create a property to store the url from the JSON

```
 //in .h file 
 @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *urlFromJSON;
```

.

```
  //in .m file
  NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"YOUR_JSON_URL_HERE"];
  NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

           //You can reach the the url using:
           self.urlFromJSON = JSON["url"]; //the key of the url in the JSON


     } failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id      JSON) {
    NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
 }];

 [operation start];
```

Good Luck ;)